# Could you advise a very good multi-button mouse for macOS?

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, mice, macos

I am looking for a **very good** mouse for my MacBook Pro (2016, 15", macOS 10.15.7).
I have just returned the *Logitech MX Master 3* because of the loudness of the left/right buttons and of how poor the BT connection is.
Here are my priorities:

- Possibly Bluetooth, first priority.
- It has at least 8-10 total programmable buttons and it needs to be possible to program it from macOS (though one could use the USB Receiver app in case that would not be possible, for example with Razer mice)
- Build quality has to be superb, I've read too much about very expensive mice getting their wheel unresponsive and/or with poor plastic-y quality.
- Possibly not Logitech because of the recent experience with their support, unless you think this is the best mouse ever.
- Compatible with iPadOS, which goes with the first priority.
- At least 8-10k DPI resolution.
- Ergonomic design or ambidextrous.

Could you advise on something that satisfies as many of these priorities as possible? If you have your experience it will be most welcome.

Thank you

Comment: By 8-10 programmable buttons, do you mean a MOBA-style mouse with a keypad on the side? Unfortunately I'm not aware of any wireless MOBA-style mice; there are some mice that are fully programmable with 8-10 buttons, but those numbers often include things like the scroll wheel and left/right click.

Comment: Yes, I meant that. In the meantime I found the Corsair Scimitar but it’s wired, so I guess it’s a matter of waiting until they make a wireless version. Thanks for your input